# Add tr below specific row

Tags: javascript

I have table with different records on each row. 
After click on "show" link in td. I want to display another tr below current tr.

I am calling "opentr" function after click on "show" link. 
How to add new tr after current tr using id of link "uniqueid"

```
<table id="table" border="0">
<th>Col 1</th> <th>Col2</th> <th>col3</th>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
    <a onclick ="opentr();" id="uniqueid">show</a>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text"></input>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text"></input>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: unclear what you're asking???

Comment: please share your js code which you have tried...

Comment: There are lots of frameworks that can do this for you. The first that comes to mind is jQuery. If you want to do it in pure javascript then maybe you can look at the jQuery source to work out a way to do this in natively. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vanilla js sample. Note the added "this" in the html's "onclick" handler.

If you wish I can show how to add a global handler that will take care of all row's onclick links.

```js
function opentr(el) {
    var currTR = el.parentNode.parentNode;
    var newTR = document.createElement("tr");
    newTR.innerHTML = "<td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td>";
    currTR.parentNode.insertBefore(newTR, currTR.nextSibling);
}
```

```css
.after { font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<table id="table" border="0">
<th>Col 1</th> <th>Col2</th> <th>col3</th>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
    <a onclick ="opentr(this);" id="uniqueid">show</a>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text"></input>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text"></input>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution in this sample
http://live.datatables.net/harurej/1/edit

and this is my code

```
        $('#tablaConsolidado tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
           var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);

           if (table.row(tr).child.isShown() ) {
               // This row is already open - close it
               table.row(tr).child.hide();
               tr.removeClass('shown');
           }
           else {
                // Open this row
                 ajax().done(function(result) {
                  // Code depending on result
                     tr.addClass('shown');
                     table.row(tr).child(
                        $(result.d)
                    ).show();

               }).fail(function() { 
                   // An error occurred
               }); 

           }
       });
```

Answer (score -1):

@Raj

I believe you are looking for something like this.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insertrow

I have pasted a slight modification of the code from that link and used your table structure.

```
<table id="myTable" border="0">
<th>Col 1</th> <th>Col2</th> <th>col3</th>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
    <a onclick ="opentr(this);" href='#' id="uniqueid">show</a>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text"></input>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text"></input>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
function opentr(anchor) {
    var currentTr = anchor.parentElement.parentElement;
    var table = currentTr.parentElement;
    var row = table.insertRow(currentTr.rowIndex);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
}
</script>
```

Comment: somewhat same but not exact. i want to add row after click on specific row . means that try button will be in any row

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
function opentr() 
{
  var oldTr = $('.uniqueid').parents("tr:first");
  var newTr = $("<tr><td></td></tr>");
  oldTr.after(newTr);
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.